# Multiple when clause inside single stage in Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins

I want to put multiple when clause in a single stage. Here is the basic example

```
def foo = 0
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
        when {
            expression {foo == 0}
        } 
            steps {
                echo 'foo is 0'
            }
        when {
            expression {foo == 1}
        } 
            steps {
                echo 'foo is 1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try this I recieve an error

```
 Multiple occurrences of the when section
```

Actually my real problem is different but solving this will probably solve my real problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks you'll be much better off using the directives as [intended](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when):

Multiple `when` is disallowed by design, if you looking a simple if else logic it's there:

1. Straghtforward `if` statement:

> ```
> stage {
>     steps {
>         script {
>             if (foo == 0){
>                 echo 'foo is 0'
>             }
>             else if (foo == 1){
>                 echo 'foo is 1'
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

If you'd like to use nested conditions in `when`: 
2. Here you go:

> ```
> stage {
>     when {
>       anyOf {
>         environment name: 'VAR_1', value: '1'
>         branch 'production'
>       }
>     }
>     steps {
>          <your steps>
>     }
> ```

Comment: Loved the answer you mentioned in the second point.

Comment: @BilalAliJafri did you ever figure out how to write this conditional Jenkinsfile and if so would you post a solution. I'm just now reading about the file and don't have a clear understanding of making a multi-conditional complex file.

Comment: You have to create a Jenkins function for getting any conditional value. And call that function to initialise your variable inside pipeline. For me I got the branch name and passed it as a argument to the function which I created. Which has multiple if clause and return values based on the branch name. :)